# It returns the total number of uppercase letters in a sentence . JAVA Recursion

Tags: java

What is the error in this code?

```
public static int buyuk(String a,int w,int q) {             
    for (int j = 65; j <=90 ; j++) {
       if(a.charAt(w)==j)           
           return buyuk(a,w+1,q+1);  
       else
           return buyuk(a,w+1,q); 
    }
    return q;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(buyuk("AlpERen",0,0));
}
```

Comment: You know that there are simpler ways of achieving this right?

Comment: what is `buyuk()` What is `a`?

Comment: paste full code , what is `a` , `w` , `q` and method `buyuk` ?

Comment: since we don't know what it is supposed to do and what it does ... how are we supposed to know?

Comment: sory Edited again. @ParkerHalo

Comment: @AlperenAvcil - Are you supposed to use recursion only?. `String#replaceAll` will do this for you in 1 line :P

Comment: This is my homework. Only recursion Unfortunately :( I did method. but I could'nt recursive. I had made an error.

Answer (score 1):

You've got some mistakes in your code. For example: The for loop will never run! It will always return in the first iteration!

You're trying to check if the character is between 65 and 90 (uppercase letter) and you should do that with compares:

```
public static int buyuk(String a,int w,int q){
    if (w == a.length())               // Stop the recursion when the end of the String is reached
        return q;
    char ch = a.charAt(w);
    if (65 <= ch && ch <= 90)          // Check if the character is an uppercase letter
        return buyuk(a, w+1, q+1);
    else
        return buyuk(a, w+1, q);
}
```

Comment: Thans @ParkerHalo :)